# why firebase keep changing the encoded code of base64 image

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im trying to convert an image to base64 so i can store it in firebase realtime database and then retrieve the encoded image and decoded it in android studio but the encoded code inside the firebase just changes after i start the app in android studio so its no longer a valid code. 
any one can tell me why the code keeps changing ?

below you se an image of the database and the code im using to retrieve the encoded code

[FireBase_Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Aoe.png)

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
    myRef.child("Products").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                byte[] image = Base64.decode(data.child("image").getValue().toString(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                list.add(new Item(R.drawable.ic_add_circle, R.drawable.ic_remove_circle,
                        ByteBuffer.wrap(image).getInt(),
                        data.child("price").getValue().toString() + " " + data.child("unit").getValue().toString(),
                        "2km",
                        data.child("discount").getValue().toString(),
                        data.child("expiration_date").getValue().toString()));
            }
            update(list);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

The value of the image should always convert to int cuz im using `setImageResource()` in my `onBindViewHolder()` method in my Adapter and that why i need it to be convertable to int.
if you cant find a solution and have a better idé of how to fix this pls tell me.
and don't worry about the update method its just to update my recycle view

Comment: You cannot change an image to int. Its not a resource. You can load your image directly in an image view.

Comment: im already doing this i’m using R.drawable.banana when creating an item and in the item constructor i have an int filed who i send R.drawable.banana to then i set it in an imageviewholder and use setImageResource() to show it in the imageview in my activity

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you don't have to convert image into Base64 and all other stuff.

Only you have to do it, upload your image into firebase-storage and get download url on image upload success.

Now store this image download URL in place of Base64 in firebase-database and display image from URL using any image loading lib like Glide or any.

Code for upload image and get download URL :

final StorageReference sRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

```
    //adding the file to reference
    //here 'destinationPath' is path my current capture image which i wants to upload
    sRef.putFile(Uri.fromFile(new File(destinationPath)))
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    //displaying success toast
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image Uploaded Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    sRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            //dismissing the progress dialog
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            //Here you will get image download url
                            String downloadUrl=uri.toString();    
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    //dismissing the progress dialog
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    //displaying the upload progress
                    double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + ((int) progress) + "%...");
                }
            });
```

That's it.

Comment: i understand your method but the problem here that i need  to get that download url before crating the product cuz the ide if this hole thing is to give the store access to the database and the store should create the product itself so when he crate a product he need to be able to directly put an image url there so the question is is there is any other way for the store to get the url directly from the firebase storage? and by doing this they link ever image to its product